# Публикация Python-приложения с библиотекой Streamlit

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сервисы, streamlit

Есть программа на python с испозованием streaml it:

```
import streamlit as st
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import maze

st.title('Maze Solver')
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose an image", ["jpg","jpeg","png"]) #image uploader
st.write('Or')
use_default_image = st.checkbox('Use default maze')
```

Открывается в браузере по адресу localhost с портом. Как ее опубликовать как web-сервис?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. использовал библиотеку http.server python и прописал в коде ip внешнего сервиса.